# Conditional test in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to check if a button is disabled without making it an assertion that passes or fails? I want to do something like:

`if(button is disabled) {
  // Run some tests
 } else {
   // Run some different tests
 }`

I know there are docs about conditional testing, but I didn't find a solution to my problem in there.

Comment: You can do count and base on that You can make decision https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html#Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the status of the button using `Jquery` and assign into a variable and check if that is `true`

```
var btnStatus = Cypress.$("#SomeIdOfButton").is(":disabled");

    if(btnStatus == true){
      // do some test here..
      })
    } else{
      // some other tests..
    }
```